# Can't access ListItem

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to get all the Tags of the listbox1.SelectedItems, so I want to use a foreach like this:

```
foreach (ListItem itm in listBox1.SelectedItems)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(itm.Tag);
        }
```

But VS2010 doesn't find "ListItem" and I need to add that specific reference.. but I can't find it. Can I do something else or where can i find that reference or assembly.

Comment: Try using the `var` keyword. Then let the compiler determine the type it is by hovering your cursor over it.

Comment: I want to retrive the tag of the item, because it's diffrent from the text of the item.

Comment: MessageBox.Show((Control(itm)).Tag) assuming you changed to use var in foreach;

Answer (score 2):

The property `listBox1.SelectedItems` returns a collection of `Object`. These are the actual objects you have selected. There is no `ListItem` object.

Try using the `var` keyword. Then let the compiler determine the type it is by hovering your cursor over it. What object type does it show you?

It appears to be `ListViewItem` however you try to use the `ListItem` type.

Comment: so how can I go throw all my listbox1.SelectedItems and show ther tagas?

Comment: It depends on the object you put in whether it supports the `Tag' property. What type of object did you put into your list?

Comment: ListViewItem itms = new ListViewItem (); itms.Text = "test"; itms.Tag="test2";

Comment: It appears to be `ListViewItem` however you try to use the `ListItem` type.

Answer (score 1):

`listBox1.SelectedItems` returns a collection of objects, so it depends on what type they are when you add them to the listBox. If you added them as Strings for example you can just do:

```
foreach (String str in listBox1.SelectedItems)
{
    MessageBox.Show(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

listBox1.SelectedItems are of type ListBox.ObjectCollection. Why are you trying to cast to ListItem??

You can create a custom object, bind it to the ListBox object using:

```
listBox1.DataSource = YOUR_CUSTOM_OBJECT_ARRAY
```

Then iterate through your items:

```
foreach (YOUR_CUSTOM_OBJECT itm in listBox1.SelectedItems)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(itm.CUSTOM_PROPERTY);
    }
```

You can find an example here:
http://mcpmag.com/articles/2004/02/01/bind-data-to-winforms-controls.aspx

Comment: I think this is a bit overkill as the `ListViewItem` has the Tag property as XandrUu wants.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to parse and display the data bound collection to your ListBox, Gordon has the answer. If you are looking to parse the visual tree and get the ListItem(s), then VisualTreeHelper class has everything you need to parse such data.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.aspx